# Pandas timestamp: modifying date and keeping time

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to modify the date of a pandas Timestamp variable but keeping the time as it is. E.g. having the following timestamp

```
time_stamp_1 = pd.Timestamp('1900-1-1 13:59')
```

I would like to set the date to the 3rd of February 2000. I.e. after the modification the print statement

```
print(time_stamp_1)
```

should return

```
2000-02-03 13:59:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html):

```
print (time_stamp_1.replace(year=2000, month=2, day=3))
2000-02-03 13:59:00
```

Or add to `Timestamp` only times converted to `timedelta` with times extracted by [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html):

```
print (pd.Timestamp('2000-02-03') + pd.Timedelta(time_stamp_1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
#alternative
print (pd.Timestamp('2000-02-03') + pd.to_timedelta(time_stamp_1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
2000-02-03 13:59:00
```

Answer (score 0):

can also do:

```
new = pd.Timestamp('2000-02-03') + pd.Timedelta(str(time_stamp_1.time()))
```

output:

```
Timestamp('2000-02-03 13:59:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do subtraction with `normalize`

```
pd.to_datetime('2000-02-03') + (time_stamp_1 - time_stamp_1.normalize())
Timestamp('2000-02-03 13:59:00')
```

---

This scales much better if you have a Series/DataFrame because it avoids `.strftime`, though is slower for a single timestamp.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('1900-1-1 13:59')]*n), 
    kernels=[
        lambda s: pd.to_datetime('2000-02-03') + (s - s.dt.normalize()),
        lambda s: pd.Timestamp('2000-02-03') + pd.to_timedelta(s.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')),
    ],
    labels=["normalize", "strftime"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(16)],
    equality_check=None,  # Because datetime type
    xlabel="len(s)"
)
```

[image]